# C++ Parameter is changed to garbage, even when called with constants

Tags: c++, memory, compiler-construction, parameters

**IT SEEMS TO BE WORKING NOW, THANKS.**

My problem is that parameters seem to be lost in one of the functions.

I am using Code::Blocks with the GNU GCC compiler on Windows 7.

Okay, I have a function that takes 6 GLfloat parameters.

```
void ProMesh::gen_quad_world(GLfloat _w,GLfloat _h,GLfloat _x1,GLfloat _y1,GLfloat _x2,GLfloat _y2);
```

As you can see, it's part of the ProMesh class.
in ProMesh I have an initializer function which calls the problematic gen_quad_world function.

```
void ProMesh::initialize(GLfloat _w, GLfloat _h,GLfloat _x1,GLfloat _y1,GLfloat _x2,GLfloat _y2)
    {
        numverts = 18;
        numtexcoords = 12;
        vert_array = NULL;
        tex_array = NULL;
        id = glGenLists(1);
        gen_quad_world(_w,_h,_x1,_y1,_x2,_y2);
    }
```

As you can see, it just passes the parameters on to gen_quad_world.

All fine so far?

Regardless of the values of _w and _h, gen_quad_world receives silly long numbers instead.

Example:
I CALL

```
gen_quad_world(1,2,345,4,5,6);
```

I GET
_w: 3.7648e-039
_h: 7.4044e+031
_x1: 345
_y1: 4
_x2: 5
_y2: 6
in the gen_quad_world function. How can that happen? This is very strange. Also, it works properly sometimes when I step through it line by line in debug mode.

Further complicating this, I have an almost identical function called gen_quad_local, which requires the same parameters. if I use that one in place of it, then it works fine.

-------------------------to see the gen_quad_world function, look below--------------------

```
void ProMesh::gen_quad_world(GLfloat _w,GLfloat _h,GLfloat _x1,GLfloat _y1,GLfloat _x2,GLfloat _y2)
{
                            std::ofstream myfile("gen_quad_world.txt");
                            myfile<<"_w: "<<_w<<"\n_h: "<<_h<<"\n";
                            myfile<<"_x1: "<<_x1<<"\n_y1: "<<_y1<<"\n";
                            myfile<<"_x2: "<<_x2<<"\n_y2: "<<_y2<<"\n";
                            myfile.close();
    glNewList(id,GL_COMPILE);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(_w,0,0);
            glVertex3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex3f(0,_h,0);
            glVertex3f(0,_h,0);
            glVertex3f(_w,_h,0);
            glVertex3f(_w,0,0);
        glEnd();
    glEndList();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `initialize` member function ?

Comment: Could you provide your implementation for the following two functions: `GLfloat`'s constructor (the one that takes an `int` parameter) and the `operator<<(const GLfloat&)` please?

Comment: Weirdness like this I'd expect from implementation not matching the interface after a lot of code changes, and would go away after a Rebuild All in VS, not sure if Code::blocks has a similar "clean then rebuild" type function?

Comment: GLfloat is not my implementation, it's part of OpenGL. It seems to be treated exactly like a float, though. I have tried these functions with other data types just to be sure.

Comment: This looks like a stack corruption. Something somewhere is apparently writing stuff where `_w` and `_h` are stored. When you suppress other calls to `gen_quad_world`, it's getting inlined and the problem disappears.

Comment: You should put a data breakpoint on one of these values to find what is overriding it. That should help.

Comment: Hey, I've got it working. I think I got the order wrong somewhere. It still doesn't explain why it wouldn't work when called with constant values, but in any case, your help has caused me to rewrite the appropriate bits and it's functioning fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @user1531548 : If you don't know what your problem was, it's very likely that it's still here and that you will encounter it again. You should take the opportunity to fix that while you still have observable symptoms.

Comment: Going over the changes I made now, it seems that I was leaving the w and h member variables in ProSlide undeclared. I checked the stack frame at a few steps and it was garbled back there already. I was calling initialize before I assigned w and h. If something else is amiss, I'm not sure what, because this appears to fix it. I'll test it extensively though, to see if anything else goes wrong, and will report back if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

imo your problems look like use of deleted objects which overwrites other structs data - check your code that works on pointers - make sure You don't call any methods of already deleted data, clear to NULL all pointers you don't use anymore (also make sure all are initialized in ctors) - this will allow you to easly find calls to foo-> of deleted objects

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling method of uninitialized object. Like this:

```
Foo *foo;
foo->method(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Comment: Nope. For one thing, this is all happening inside ProMesh. For another, it works for half the parameters, it's only those first two that seem to be plagued by this.

Comment: Oh, and strange new development. There is a call to this function in another class, but that is never used. That code is never run. However, I changed it now to use a dummy function, and suddenly this function works?

Comment: In the constructor of the class that contains a pointer to ProMesh, I call this:
mesh = new ProMesh(_w,_h,_x1,_y1,_x2,_y2);
Is that sufficient? :s

Comment: @user1531548: you can delete it later and make a call on garbage pointer